# Use pandas in order to create a new df from another and fill it with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hel lo I would need help in order to create a nex df from this one :

```
      Groups                   COL1  COL2     COL3  COL4  COL5
0     G1      DJJE):Canis_lupus  ABFC  Canidae     4     3
1     G1      JUUI):Canis_canis    YH  Canidae    10    12
2     G1        KI):Lupus_lupus    ZA  canidae     2    12
3     G2  IOZ):Felis_sylvestris    OP  Falidae     0     2
4     G2        KI):Felis_felis    UI  Falidae     6     8
5     G3        YY):Canis_lupus    ER  Raninae     7     9
6     G3        SD):Canis_lupus    GH  Raninae     2     3
7     G3        DZ:)Lupus_lupus    EZ  Raninae     6     8
8     G4           KUU):O_outan    LO  Babounae    4     8
9     G4   OK:)Felis_sylvestris    IO  Babounae    4     8
9     G4   LK:)Felis_sylvestris    IU  Babounae    8     9
```

The idea is for each `Groups` to create a df wth a column `COL3`  as first column and then fill it by adding new column and letters.

Here is an exemple :

`G1` is composed of `3 different Names` (after the `:)` pattern) :
 - `Canis_lupus` 
 - `Canis_canis` 
 - `Lupus_lupus`

then if `COL4` and `COL5` of the values are both `> 5` I assign the value `A` in the new df 
and if `COL4` and `COL5 < 5` then I assign the value `B` in the new df

ex `DJJE):Canis_lupus` have both `COL4 and COL5 < 5` then `Canis_lupus` in `Canidae` will have a `B` value.

ex  `YY):Canis_lupus` in `G3 h`ave `COL4 and COL5 > 5` then `Canis_lupus` in the `Raninae` will have a `A` value

if there is a case where there is both `COL4 and COL5 > 5` and `COL4 and COL5 < 5` as for exemple :

`row5` and `row6` for `Canis_lupus` in `Raninae`, then A > B so I give the letter A.

if `COL4 > 5` and `COL5 < 5` then I give the letter `B`

if `COL4 < 5` and `COL5 > 5` then I give the letter `B`
here is the expected output :

```
COL3     Canis_lupus Canis_canis Lupus_lupus Felis_sylvestris O_outan 
Canidae  B           A           A           NA               NA   
Falidae  A           NA          NA          B                A    
Raninae  A           NA          A           NA               NA  
Babounae NA          NA          NA          A                B
```

and here are the data :

`{'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G2', 4: 'G2', 5: 'G3', 6: 'G3', 7: 'G3', 8: 'G4', 9: 'G4', 10: 'G4'}, 'COL1': {0: 'DJJE):Canis_lupus', 1: 'JUUI):Canis_canis', 2: 'KI):Lupus_lupus', 3: 'IOZ):Felis_sylvestris', 4: 'KI):Felis_felis', 5: 'YY):Canis_lupus', 6: 'SD):Canis_lupus', 7: 'DZ:)Lupus_lupus', 8: 'KUU):O_outan', 9: 'OK:)Felis_sylvestris', 10: 'LK:)Felis_sylvestris'}, 'COL2': {0: 'ABFC', 1: 'YH', 2: 'ZA', 3: 'OP', 4: 'UI', 5: 'ER', 6: 'GH', 7: 'EZ', 8: 'LO', 9: 'IO', 10: 'IU'}, 'COL3': {0: 'Canidae', 1: 'Canidae', 2: 'canidae', 3: 'Falidae', 4: 'Falidae', 5: 'Raninae', 6: 'Raninae', 7: 'Raninae', 8: 'Babounae', 9: 'Babounae', 10: 'Babounae'}, 'COL4': {0: 4, 1: 10, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 6, 5: 7, 6: 2, 7: 6, 8: 4, 9: 4, 10: 8}, 'COL5': {0: 3, 1: 12, 2: 12, 3: 2, 4: 8, 5: 9, 6: 3, 7: 8, 8: 8, 9: 8, 10: 9}}`

Comment: Raninae has rows that are both greater than and less than 5. How do u handle that. also for canidae it has a row where col 4 is less than 5 and col 5 is greater than 5. u dont have a condition for that

Comment: @sammywemmy if we have two diffrent cases, then the one with rows greater then 5 wins so the cell has the letter A

Comment: @sammywemmy do you have an idea ?

Comment: tot sb else would pick this up ... i'll give it a go

Comment: Also Edit ur code to cover all conditions, e.g. index 2 where col A is less than 5 and col B is greater than 5 ...

Comment: @sammywemmy thank you, I updated with a more suitable exemples

Comment: u just posted R data structure, instead of Pandas